# Blending artifacts when rendering polygon hair with Three.js

Tags: three.js

Trying to render polygon hair with transparency I get this artifact:

[image: Polygon hair artifacts]

What I've checked so far:

1. `renderer.sortObjects` is true.
2. The hair's `material.side` is THREE.DoubleSide.
3. Set `material.alphaTest=0.5` - reduced the problem but some artifacts are still visible.

How do I debug this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three.js self transparency with intersecting polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735792/three-js-self-transparency-with-intersecting-polygons)

Comment: See also [What does Material.alphaTest mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305917/what-does-material-alphatest-mean)

Comment: @PeterO. it's not a duplicate of that question as I noticed that using this approach still generated noticeable artifacts. I found another solution though (edited the question and answer accordingly).

Comment: See also [Transparent objects in Threejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs/15995475#15995475)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What solved the problem was rendering the hair twice, first the back side and then the front side:

```
    var hairMesh1 = obj;
    var hairMaterial1 = hairMesh1.material;
    hairMaterial1.opacity = 1.0;
    hairMaterial1.transparent = true;
    hairMaterial1.side = THREE.BackSide;
    hairMaterial1.depthWrite = false;

    var hairMesh2 = hairMesh1.clone();
    var hairMaterial2 = hairMesh2.material = hairMesh2.material.clone();
    hairMaterial2.side = THREE.FrontSide;

    var hairObj2 = new THREE.Object3D();
    hairObj2.add(hairMesh2)
    hairObj2.renderOrder = 1;

    model.add(hairObj1);
    model.add(hairObj2);
```

This is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs/15995475#15995475).

Another thing I tried was like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735792/three-js-self-transparency-with-intersecting-polygons) - I set

```
material.alphaTest = 0.5; // between 0 and 1
```

which reduced problem (still noticeable artifacts seen). An explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305917/what-does-material-alphatest-mean).